# Zero-height of ScrollViewer-templated item inside ItemsControl?

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer, itemscontrol

I have an `ItemsControl` with arbitrary items. Some of the items are wrapped inside a `ScrollViewer`. The code-behind for these scrollable items makes use of the `ViewportWidth` (almost equivalent to `ActualWidth`) and `ViewportHeight` (almost equivalent to `ActualHeight`) properties to arrange/size its visual children. This works as long as I don't put the item inside an `ItemsControl`. When the item appears in an `ItemsControl` the value of `ViewportHeight` equals 0 - effectively making my item invisible. Note that I want to arrange the items vertically, giving all items equal height! No fancy stuff, just a regular `StackPanel`.

The templates are applied automatically using `DataType`:

```
<MyControl.Resources>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyScrollableItem}">
      <MyControlWrappedInScrollViewer Text="{Binding Text}" />
   </DataTemplate>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyItem}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
   </DataTemplate>
</MyControl.Resources>
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" />
```

The structure of `MyControlWrappedInScrollViewer` looks something like this:

```
<UserControl>
   <Grid>
      <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
          <Canvas />
      </ScrollViewer>
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Why does my `ScrollViewer` get the height of 0? How can I tell my `ItemsControl` to size the item appropriately?** E.g. One item yields a height of the ItemsControl height. Two items yield half of it, and so on.

Comment: All sort of funny stuff can happen when you wrap items in a ScrollViewer inside an item that has a ScrollViewer (ItemsControl); besides that it smell like a bad design decision i.e. this is not user-friendly at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="1" IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```